# Error while install installing pykpass

Tags: python, installation, kerberos

I am encountering following error on installing pykpass module from http://www.huque.com/software/pykpass/ . Following is the error :

```
wrap_kpass.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
wrap_kpass.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
wrap_kpass.c:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
wrap_kpass.c:31: error: array type has incomplete element type
wrap_kpass.c:32: error: ‘wrap_kpass’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wrap_kpass.c:32: error: ‘METH_VARARGS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wrap_kpass.c:42: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘init_kpass’
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: For the first error: are you running it on Linux? Because the Python headers file are included in `python-dev` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Python.h: No such file or directory

Probably you forgot to install package `python-dev` or any other form of Python development headers.